# Simple Primitive Elements in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, builder, primitive

Normally on other IDEs, I simply drag a Rectangle object to the body or content of my application then resize it, define colors, etc. What I discovered in Flex 4 (Flash Builder 4) was that it's not just like that (or is it?) and I can't seem to find something to drag to my application to create a Rectangle object.

My question is, how do I do it? How do I create a simple Rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just figured out how to deal with it. I just make a new component and base it on **spark.primitives.Rect**. Then after that, I just assign the **fill**'s  **SolidColor** to whatever I need just like my component code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Rect xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var fillColor:String;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="{fillColor}" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

Not sure if this is the best way but it works for me so I'll go along with it. :)

Comment: I really like the new Spark primitives! But aside from Catalyst you can also create in the Flash IDE and import to your Flex Builder project via a .swc or emdedding a .swf. I do remember seeing a demo last year from the Adobe guys where the Flash IDE (CS5) to Flash Builder integration was seamless... but it does mean you need to buy Flash CS5

Comment: Yes, and apparently I don't know Flash so buying it would be pointless. xD

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for FXG elements in Flash Builder Design mode.
What you can do is, use Flash Catalyst, draw your primitives with it and copy/paste the generated code in Flash Builder.

Comment: What if I don't have Flash Catalyst? Isn't there some way to achieve it?

Comment: Ouch.. so that means I'll have to get Flash Catalyst as well.. :/

Comment: @Shedo Chung-Hee Surashu You can always write things by hand, such as is demonstrated by your own answer to the question.  Many other Adobe software will export to the FXG format, which I thought could be be used in a Flex project somehow.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f26c150d412357de3591-8000.html